# Unusual Solve[] behavior delay

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For a project that involved computing bond lengths from spectroscopic data, I used `Solve[]` to solve a fairly simple equation for an unknown. I began noticing "unusual" behavior when I changed the input. Specifically, when I changed a number and Solve'd, the result is the answer previously. Executing the code again, however, gives the correct answer; it's like there's a delay of one execution. 
Here's an example:

```
B = (11.09 + del)*2.998*10^10;

c = h*1000*n*10^20/(8 \[Pi]^2);

h = 6.62618*10^-34;

n = 6.02204*10^23;

del = 0;

Solve[c/B == 0.97959253 R^2, R]
```

Executing gives

```
{{R -> -1.24567}, {R -> 1.24567}}
```

However, when I change `del = 0` to `del = 10` in the above block, I get the same answer when I execute! When I execute the block a second time, I get the correct answer:

```
{{R -> -0.903299}, {R -> 0.903299}}
```

Then, changing `del = 10` back to `del = 0` and executing gives:

```
{{R -> -0.903299}, {R -> 0.903299}}
```

and as you can imagine, executing the block a second time gives the correct answer

```
{{R -> -1.24567}, {R -> 1.24567}}
```

There is nothing special about 0 and 10, any 2 numbers work. It's like this `Solve[]` block has a delay effect...

I'm not sure if this is a quirk of my computer (MacBook Intel) or if it's something inherent in Solve. Tell me if you guys get the same behavior as I did when running this code, and if so, do you have any idea why this is happening? (I have tried restarting Mathematica and running it again, and it always behaves this way).

Comment: Just making sure the obvious. Upon changing the value of `del` did you evaluate other assignments to update their value ? Mathematica will no do that automatically for you.

Comment: Hello PJR, welcome to StackOverflow.  See [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if you have question about the site.  Please remember to [vote for and accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) good answers.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your `del` definition is after some others where `del` is present. Therefore, at the time when those execute, `del` still has its old value. You have 2 choices: either place `del` assignment on top:

```
del = 0;
B = (11.09 + del)*2.998*10^10;
c = h*1000*n*10^20/(8 Pi^2);
h = 6.62618*10^-34;
n = 6.02204*10^23;
Solve[c/B == 0.97959253 R^2, R]
```

or use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) for assignment:

```
B := (11.09 + del)*2.998*10^10;
c := h*1000*n*10^20/(8 Pi^2);
h = 6.62618*10^-34;
n = 6.02204*10^23;
del = 0;
Solve[c/B == 0.97959253 R^2, R]
```

Comment: Yeah I actually just figured that out a couple minutes ago while I was looking at it! Oops, feel kind of dumb now... thanks Leonid. Seeing as this post is kind of useless, is there some way I can delete it?

Comment: @PJR, if you really want to delete this post, click the word "flag" at the bottom of your question.  Select "Other" and explain to the moderator that you want this deleted.  Mind you, they may not follow your wishes.  As stated before, my opinion is that it is useful to others, and Leonid took his time to answer it, so it should remain.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution to PJR's problem is just adding

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

beofroe the code. Then the changes of `del` will have no chance to redefine `B`. ^_^